# Redirect to Post Method/Action

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an ActionResult that accepts POST, however is there a work around for me to redirect from a controller to another controller containing this POST method/action???

Here is signature of the method I am redirecting to;

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
 [Transaction]
 [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
 public ActionResult Edit(Payment payment, PaymentApplication paymentApplication, string exchangeId, bool manual, int firstPaymentId, int? exchangeEventId, bool addOnly)
{

}
```

Comment: I don't understand why you'd want to do this, but I'll play along :-) What does the signature of the method that you are in? Could you simply call the action method it? E.g. inside your current action call `return MyOtherController.Edit(payment, paymentApplication)`

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `RedirectToAction` to call a POST method. For your specific need, just new the controller and call the method directly from the other controller, passing whatever the parameters.

```
var controller = new YourControllerWithMethodToCall();
controller.Edit(payment, etc...);
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do it simply

```
       <% using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "AnotherController", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "formNameHere" }))
           {%>
    //form content here

<input type="submit" Value="Post Me" id="PostMe">
     <%} %>
```

in ActionNameParameter you can write your Action, and in ControllerNameParameter you can write controllername which ou want to post datas.

Comment: What u show here is page behind and that would not work for me. I am in a controller and I want to redirect to an action in another controller whose property is POST..how do I accomplish that???

Comment: it will redirect you to edit action of given controller. You want to redirect from Controller? if so then you can use RedirectToAction("ActionName","ControllerName")

Comment: RedirectToAction works for an Action that has POST property??

Comment: because I am inside a controller and I am trying to get to a method whose property is POST.

Comment: maybe i did not understand you. Can not you write your code it any method and call it. Why yo want call [POST] Action?