# How To Render Correct View when Calling Post Action of Another Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

A Login Action on my AccountController uses the technique mentioned by [Ε Г И І И О](https://stackoverflow.com/users/687190/) in [Redirect to Post Method/Action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5460681/redirect-to-post-method-action) to post a "Login Successful" message to a Success Action of my StatusController:

```cs
/// <returns>
/// If login is successful, returns a view stating such.  If the
/// login is not successful, the main Login view will be 
/// redisplayed 
/// </returns>
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(logIn loginAttempt)
{
    logIn theLoginModel = new logIn();

    string username = loginAttempt.Username; 
    string password = loginAttempt.Password; 
    if (Membership.ValidateUser(username, password)) {     
       ...

       /* The login was successful.  Redirect to the LoginSucess
        * Action success */
       status theStatus = new status();
       theStatus.Message = Constants.StatusMsgs.LoginSuccess;
       StatusController SC = new StatusController();
       return SC.Success(theStatus);            
    } else {
       ...
       return View(theLoginModel);
    }                  
}
```

I can use the VS2010 debugger to verify that my Success Action gets the correct message in code fragment:

```cs
namespace usedCarLotWebApp.Controllers
{
   public class StatusController : Controller
   {
      /// <summary>
      /// Outputs a Success status message to the user
      /// </summary>
      /// <returns>
      /// A trivial view to display a Success status message to the 
      /// user
      /// </returns>
      [HttpPost]
      public ActionResult Success(status theMessage)
      {
         return View(viewName: "Success", model: theMessage);
      }
   }
}
```

but when the Success Action of my Status Controller tries to render the view, it attempts to render a view from my AccountController Directory instead of my StatusController Directory as I would expect.

Is there some way I can modify the Success Action of my StatusController so that it *always* tries to find a Success View in my StatusController Directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TempData` is the way to go. `TempData` is a collection, that stores values until next request. When you redirect, you go directly to next request, where you retrieve values from `TempData`. I do it all the time to pass status messages.

I would do it like that:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(logIn loginAttempt)
{
    logIn theLoginModel = new logIn();

    string username = loginAttempt.Username; 
    string password = loginAttempt.Password; 
    if (Membership.ValidateUser(username, password)) {     
       TempData["Message"] = theMessage;
       return RedirectToAction("Success", "Status");      
    } else {
       ...
       return View(theLoginModel);
    }                  
}
```

Status controller (please notice `status theMessage` disappears from action header, because it is passed in `TempData`). `Success` also becomes `GET` message:

```
namespace usedCarLotWebApp.Controllers
{
   public class StatusController : Controller
   {
      [HttpGet]
      public ActionResult Success()
      {
         var theMessage = (theMessageType) TempData["Message"];
         return View(viewName: "Success", model: theMessage);
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should return a redirection as a response instead of trying to call the method on a controller instance.

```
return RedirectToAction("Success", "Status")
```

or

```
return RedirectToAction("Success", "Status", new { theMessage = Constants.StatusMsgs.LoginSuccess})
```

Also you can send the parameter in Success action.

```
//[HttpPost] You don't need this
public ActionResult Success()
{
   return View("Success",Constants.StatusMsgs.LoginSuccess);
}
```

Comment: If I do that, is there a way I can *post* my status object instead of passing it via a URL parameter?   NOTE: the LoginSuccess item will not be constant.

Comment: @ShawnEary Yes you can still pass it as a parameter. Look at the RedirectToAction overloads.

Comment: @ShawnEary I didn't notice theMessage parameter has a custom type. If status type has a default constructor and public properties, model binder should be able to send it in the querystring.

Comment: Yes.  I was originally thinking about using your RedirectToAction approach, but I'm thinking it will pass my data via the QueryString and I'm *hoping* to keep the Query String clean.  That's why I wanted to try using a *post* operation.

Comment: @ShawnEary Post-Redirect-Get patterns requires a GET request at the end. Maybe you can create an action named LoginSuccess and select the message inside.